# Numeric keypad by default using libgdx

Tags: libgdx, textfield

I have 3 `TextField`s to introduce the day, month and year.
At the moment i show the `KeyPad`, but the user needs to switch to the `numeric KeyPad` manually.
How can I set up a numeric keypad by default for a textfield in libgdx?

Comment: You mean, that a numeric keypad showes, when the `Textfield` gets the focus?

Comment: Yeah, it is that I want

Comment: You can add a `FocusListener` to your `TextField` and when the `Event` gets fired (the `TextField` gets the focus), you can show the numeric keypad.

Comment: Yes, I know how to handle the events, my problem is that I don't know how to call the numeric keypad using libgdx.

Comment: You wrote "Numeric keypad by default". does that mean, that you were able to show the numeric keypad? If yes how?

Comment: Yeah, I should have explain better. The problem is that I am not able to show the numeric keypad with Libgdx. I have 3 TextField to introduce the day, month and year. Right now keypad is showing, but not numeric keypad by default. Then user have to change it manually, and it is annoying. Thats the main problem, I just want a numeric keypad for these textfields,

Comment: Wow a great idea came into my mind. But i am not sure if it works... You can fire `Event`s manually right? Why don't you fire the `Event`, for the `Key`, which is used to switch to `numeric KeyPad`?

Comment: Mmmh.. I will try!! Hope it works..

Comment: I think in your `FocusEvent` you need to create a `new InputEvent` and call `setKeyCode(Keys.SWITCH_CHARSET)` and then call `fire(inputEvent)`. I am not 100% sure if it is the right keycode. But to try that you could set a breakpoint, press the key and look at the keycode.

Comment: Wow it seems very difficult, there are too many things to override

Comment: Why? Can't you simply call `fire` inside your `FocusListener` `Event`

Comment: TextField only accepts TextFieldListener and TextFieldFilter. I don't know where to add the FocusListener :(

Comment: `textfield.addListener(new FocusListener...)` should work.

Comment: But you allready show the `onscreenKeyboard` right? When do you show that? Simply add the `fire` event there.

Comment: `tf_dia.addListener(new FocusListener() {
                                          public void keyboardFocusChanged (FocusEvent event, Actor actor, boolean focused) {
    InputEvent tn = new InputEvent();
    tn.setKeyCode(Keys.SWITCH_CHARSET);
                            actor.fire(tn);
   }
                                                                    } );` I get a nullpointexception doing this. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: You need to tell me where the `NullPointer` happens and what it says

Comment: In actor.fire(tn). That inputevent has a null exception somehow..

Comment: Is the `actor` null? Or what is null? What does the exception say? Also don't forget to set up your onscreenKeyboard. Maybe thats the problem. It can't fire an Event, as there is no onscreen KeyBoard.

Comment: I used now the onScreenKeyboard. Still got the same error Nullpointer when I call fire method.`tf_dia.setOnscreenKeyboard(new OnscreenKeyboard() {                                          @Override                                                         public void show(boolean visible) {                             if(visible==true){                        InputEvent tn = new InputEvent()    tn.setKeyCode(Keys.SWITCH_CHARSET);                tn.setRelatedActor(tf_dia);                         tf_dia.fire(tn);                                  }                                                }`

Comment: If you use debug mode you can see the exact line where it happens. Can you show me that?

Comment: It seems, like `Event`s are `fired` by an `Actor` (in your case the `TextField`), and they are `fired` to the `Actor` (again your `TextField`) and the `Actor` (again your `TextField`) is set as the target `Actor`. So not the `onScreenKeyBoard` recives the `Event` but your `TextField`... I think you should ask in the `Libgdx` forums, or post an issue.

Comment: Ok... anyway very thanks for your help Springbua.. :)

Comment: Do you ask in the forums? Or post an issue? If yes please tell me what they said. I am interested in this for some reason^^

Comment: Yeah I post an issue =) You just have awesome ideas !! http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=13676

Comment: :P If they can't help you you ca create your own `KeyPad` with `Scene2d` `Button`s... At least that would work^^

Comment: Do you have any tutorial to follow steps?? =))

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui and https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout should help^^