# How to show numpad on Libgdx Textfield?

Tags: libgdx

I'm not the first to ask this question but no question has answers so far, just comments on using focus, would you please post a working answer on how to show numpad on certain textfields in Libgdx?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to show NumPad on `TextField` in LibGDX, but in android it can be easily achieved so you can use [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) to work with LibGDX.

I've some helpful links for you :

1. [Numeric keypad by default using libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982226/numeric-keypad-by-default-using-libgdx)
2. [How to press a key programmatically in a TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221188/how-to-press-a-key-programmatically-in-a-textfield)